# How to Remove the More Info Link from RSS Feeds in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, rss

I need to remove the "more info" link from feeds.  It appears that the link is added to the content in place of the break tag, but I see no option to disable this substitution for RSS feeds only.  I am generating the feeds using a feed display in a view.  Can anyone tell me how I can remove the "more info" link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In vides it's possible to enable and disable a see more link. So most likely you can just turn it off. Take a look a the left column in the views UI.

Comment: I assumed the same thing, but have spent a lot of time looking with no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following out:

First, I'm sure your in your view its `Style: RSS Feed`. Also make sure `Row style: Node`.

Besides the `Row style: Node` there is a Button (shaped like a circular gear). Click on it.

The following display types are available:

1. Use default RSS settings
2. Full Text
3. Title plus teaser
4. Title only

Choose option number (2)

Comment: That would normally work well, but some of the entries are quite long.  This has become a problem because Outlook's reader also add something similar to "read more", so it becomes redundant.  The majority of the people reading the feeds will be using Outlook, and the others can still click on the title to see the full content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a RSS-view.

(Sorry if I use wrong terminology as I use a Swedish translation of Drupal)

Then make a page and make the urlpath the exact same as for the feed (eg. aggregator/sources/10 for feed nr. 10)

This will replace the default list of rssposts and instead show your custom rss-view without the "show more" links.

This worked for me at least. Let me know if you need more info...

/Kristian